# Action Script 3 .Loop the animation 3 times and stop

Tags: actionscript-3

I working on Flash banners and I would like the animation to loop 3 times and then stop. I don't know Action Script but I found this code:

On the 1st frame I used this:

```
_root.loops_played = 0;

if (_root.loops_played >= 3){

stop(); //*

} else {

play();

}
```

On the last frame:

```
_root.loops_played += 1;
```

Unfortunately the animation keeps looping and I get this error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 1   1120: Access of undefined property _root.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 3   1120: Access of undefined property _root.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 175, Line 1 1120: Access of undefined property _root.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 175, Line 1 1120: Access of undefined property _root.
```

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_root doesn't exist in AS3. It is an AS2 thing.

Still, to get your current logic running, use `this` instead of `_root`.

Here is some code with not much changes to what you provided:

First Frame:

```
if(!this.loops_played) this.loops_played = 1;

if(this.loops_played >= 3) stop(); else play();
```

Last Frame:

```
this.loops_played++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this code into the last frame or where you want to stop your movie after playing 3 times.

```
if(!loopCount){var loopCount:Number = 0;}
loopCount++;
if(loopCount >= 3){stop();}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler explicitly tells you that the `_root` property is undefined. You can not use undefined properties and objects.

`_root` does not exist in AS3 any more, there is a slightly comparable property `root`. Keep in mind that `root` is not global.

Comment: Thank you!
I also found this: 
var loopCounter:int = 0;

loopCounter++;
if(loopCounter < 3){
     gotoAndPlay(2);
} 
And it worked!

Comment: If local variable is a suitable in your case, use it.